# How to fix iOS Simulator issue?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

When I run iOS simulator it only runs in (3,5 - inches) and when I change it to (4-inches), this is the error that pops up in the "debug navigator" under "thread 1":

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

how do I fix/correct this issue, so that my app can work on both 3.5 inches and 4 inches iPhone Retina screens & in the Simulator?

Thank you.

Comment: there must be more to the error, you just display your main.m file. This happens often when a memory bad_access_ or similar happens. There should be more to extract from the console.

Comment: Yes there is more to the error - for instance, I'll run the simulator and it launches in a 3.5 display, when I change the device while in simulator mode (Hardware>Device>iPhoneRetina (4-inches)) the simulator crashes and the errors pop up:

    0x1ea7f7a:  ret

Comment: @JamesRob Please paste the contents of Xcode's console log here so we can better help you.

Comment: If you have an error message why you don't show it to us? all the information inside your post doesn't help us.

Comment: Guys - I run simulator and  in simulator i change the Device to (iPhone Retina 4 inches) and it crashes - -Thats the only error I get-> (lldb) I Need my app to run in both 3.5 inches and 4 inches on the simulator without it crashing!

Comment: When you change the device while running an app in the simulator it will be terminated. To check your app on a 4-inch device change the device type in Xcode before running your app again.

Answer (score 1):

You should insert a `breakpoint` for all `exceptions` that will occure. 
Thisfore go to the `Breakpoint Navigator`

[image]

and add at the bottom of `xCode` an `Exception Breakpoint...`

[image]

The `Breakpoint` should be set like this

[image]

No you should be able to get a error message inside the `log` and also see whats the problem.

Comment: I'll be uploading a video soon on youtube!

Comment: but you normally have to get an error message. If you add an `Exception Breakpoint` like described the log will print out whats the problem otherwise its possible you don't get any message. I don't think a video can really describe whats the problem because nobody knows your code.